# How do I set the meta key with the meta convert feature in most *nix terminals?

Tags: linux, terminal, vi

.Xdefaults:

```
xterm*eightBitInput: false
```

This command apparently allows you to use a meta key + *something* to enter vi editing mode in a linux terminal. But **what is the meta key and how do you set the *something***?

refrence:
[Barts Blog](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/20040326082602)

Comment: The Meta key is usually assigned to the Windows key on keyboards designed for Windows or the Command key on Mac keyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *usual* assignment is debatable, because there is no key labelled <kbd>*Meta*</kbd> on your keyboard.  As noted in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Alt-and-Meta-Keys)

> Many keyboards have keys labeled *"Alt"*.  Few have keys labeled *"Meta"*.
>   However, **`xterm`**'s default translations use the Meta modifier.  Common
>   keyboard configurations assign the Meta modifier to an *"Alt"* key.  By
>   using **`xmodmap`** one may have the modifier assigned to a different key, and
>   have "real" alt and meta keys.

**`xterm`** treats it as a *modifier* key, like <kbd>*Shift*</kbd>, or <kbd>*Control*</kbd>.

However, X11 does not define a *modifier* named <kbd>*Meta*</kbd>.

In `xterm`, the assumption is that it *usually* is assigned to one of the <kbd>*Alt*</kbd> keys, and that the user may have used `xmodmap` to alter the assignment, like this example from *XTerm Control Sequences*:

```
 ! put meta on mod3 to distinguish it from alt
 keycode 64 = Alt_L
 clear mod1
 add mod1 = Alt_L
 keycode 115 = Meta_L
 clear mod3
 add mod3 = Meta_L
```

Just in case *Meta* is not one of the <kbd>*Alt*</kbd> keys (assuming that's labelled on your keyboard), `xterm` has a resource setting to help, named [*altIsNotMeta*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:altIsNotMeta):

> If "true", treat the Alt-key as if it were the Meta-key.  Your
>   keyboard may happen to be configured so they are the same.  But
>   if they are not, this allows you to use the same prefix- and
>   shifting operations with the Alt-key as with the Meta-key.  See
>   [**`altSendsEscape`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:altSendsEscape) and [**`metaSendsEscape`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:metaSendsEscape).  The default is "false".